# How to use except with numbers in my loop

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, except

I am trying to write a short python script.
My objective is simple: the code has to ask you to choose between writing "1" or "2".  If you choose 1, you obtain a list in the console if you write 2, you get a CSV file. Also, when you write anything that is not a number the code ask you to write again. So all these functions are working well so far, the problem is that when you write any other number that is not 1 o 2, the script simply finishes itself.
What could I do to include in the except other numbers?

This is the script:

```
while True:
    try:
        answer = int(input("Press 1 to see protein ID in console \nPress 2 to export protein CSV list \nChoose="))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, not what I was expecting \nTry again")
        continue
    else:
        break
if answer== 1:
    from ProteinHtmlID import ProteinHtmlID 

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        protein = ProteinHtmlID("protein.html") #name of the file you want check
        name = protein.getFileName()
        print(name)
    
        count = protein.searchProtein("Acidobacterium ailaaui")
        print(count)
    
        found = protein.findAllProteinNames()
        print(found)
elif answer== 2:
    import pandas as pd
    from ProteinHtmlID import ProteinHtmlID 
    
    #prot_name = ProteinHtmlID("protein.html")
    wp_num = ProteinHtmlID("protein.html")
    
    #found = prot_name.findAllProteinNames()
    found = wp_num.findAllProteinNames()
    
    #prot_name = []
    places = []
    wp_num = []
    
    for elem in found:
      #prot_name.append(elem)
      wp_num.append(elem)
      places.append(found[elem])
      
    
    #data = {'Name' : prot_name, 'Place' : places, 'ID' : wp_num}
    data = {'Place' : places, 'ID' : wp_num}
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.to_csv('chitin_names.csv', index=False)
    print(dataframe)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since except checks for errors, you can't easily include the fact that `answer` is 1 or 2. Instead, simply do another check before the `break` :

```py
while True:
    try:
        answer = int(input("Press 1 to see protein ID in console \nPress 2 to export protein CSV list \nChoose="))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, not what I was expecting \nTry again")
        continue
    else: # Can't use elif on try...catch if I remember well
        if answer == 1 or answer == 2: # Check answer is 1 or 2. Otherwise, the loop continues
            break
```

Note that using `continue` and `else` together here is useless.

By the way, I'd rather write your code as follows, I find it neater :

```py
while True:
    try:
        answer = int(input("Press 1 to see protein ID in console \nPress 2 to export protein CSV list \nChoose="))
        if answer == 1 or answer == 2:
            break
    except ValueError:
        pass
    print("Sorry, not what I was expecting \nTry again")
```

What this does is to stop the loop only if `answer` is 1 or 2, and continue on the loop otherwise, and then later in the loop you write the error message. (The `except ValueError: pass` allows to continue the loop as if there was no `ValueError`).

Answer (score 2):

If the user inputs a valid number that is not 1 or 2, you won't get a `ValueError`, so the script simply exits the while loop.

You can add a check in the `try` block to avoid this:

```py
if ans < 1 or ans > 2:
    continue
```